# Azure Resource Manager gives an error on the deployment

Tags: api, azure, deployment, azure-resource-manager

I am getting an error when Azure Resource Manager (ARM) is deploying my template on Azure. This part crashes:

```
{
  "comments": "Some comments.",
  "tags": {
    "displayName": "Server IP Address"
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
  "name": "[variables('publicIPAddressesDevTableauServerIpName')]",
  "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",
  "properties": {
    "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Static",
    "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4,
    "dnsSettings": {
      "domainNameLabel": "[parameters('tableauResourceGroupName')]"
    }
  },
  "dependsOn": []
},
```

Error that I am getting:

```
{
 "error": {
    "code": "NoRegisteredProviderFound",
    "message": "No registered resource provider found for location 'westeurope' and API version '2017-09-01' for type 'publicIPAddresses'. The supported api-versions are '2014-12-01-preview, 2015-05-01-preview, 2015-06-15, 2016-03-30, 2016-06-01, 2016-07-01, 2016-08-01, 2016-09-01, 2016-10-01, 2016-11-01, 2016-12-01, 2017-03-01, 2017-04-01, 2017-06-01, 2017-08-01, 2017-09-01'. The supported locations are 'westus, eastus, northeurope, westeurope, eastasia, southeastasia, northcentralus, southcentralus, centralus, eastus2, japaneast, japanwest, brazilsouth, australiaeast, australiasoutheast, centralindia, southindia, westindia, canadacentral, canadaeast, westcentralus, westus2, ukwest, uksouth, koreacentral, koreasouth'."
  }
}
```

I have tried the different API versions but no luck. Anyone who has some ideas why it might be happening? It was working till 3rd of September abut from 4th stopped. I assume that Microsoft rolled out some updates on the API Versioning.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are either deploying the wrong file or didn't save the file or something like that. Because `"2017-06-01"` (what you have in this example) is a supported API-version and it says `2017-09-01 isn't supported`.

ps. despite `2017-09-01` is listed as supported its not working for me either, so revert to `2017-06-01`. its not like you are sacrificing anything

Comment: Thank you for the promt anwer. I have however no place where I use 2017-09-01 api version in code, it seems that Azure somehow is taking it by mistake. I have tried different api versions other than 2017-09-01 or 2017-06-01, but no luck. Where do I have to save the file then?

Comment: well, i don't know how or what are you deploying, but if this is the code you tihnk you are deploying, you are not deploying this code. azure won't replace anything in your templates

Comment: So, finally got a response from Microsoft, was an error on their site.

Comment: is it fixed now? @pacer05

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem for the same resource type (Network/publicIPAddresses) with the same apiVersion (2017-06-01) deployed in the same location (westeurope) through ARM CLI (azure-cli 2.0.16). I am sure I had everything saved with correct content and my ARM templates are git controlled and worked smoothly as of 2017-07.

What is interesting, is that pub IP resource is created, deployment logs in Azure Portal show OK, but then are followed with a BadRequest for the same resource 2 second later.

There could be multiple explanations to that, but my bet is on some bug with the azure-cli which has been recently updated on my Ubuntu workstation.

Also, if you noticed, the error message contradicts itself by saying that apiVersion 2017-09-01 is not supported and then lists it as supported.

Similar thing happened to me more than once when MS introduces new API version for some resource type but azure-cli is not of the latest version.

If ignoring the problem does not help and it does not create the resource for you, then, try to update azure-cli to the latest version following MS guidelines [from here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest).

If it does not help,open a bug report [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues), this is definitely not a problem with your ARM template.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, we opened a ticket by Microsoft and are waiting for the answer. As soon as we get it I post the outcome.

Comment: So, finally got a response from Microsoft, was an error on their site.